# Critical points of constrained optimization problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

$f(x,y) = x^2+2y^2$
. Solve for critical points of *f* along the curve $h(x,y) = x^4+y^4-1=0$, where $x,y \in [0,1]$.

We set:
$\nabla f(x) = \lambda\nabla h(x)$
$h(x) = 0$

Above gives the equations:
(1) $2x = 4\lambda x^3$, (2) $4y=4\lambda y^3$,  (3) $x^4+y^4-1=0$.

***I solved the above equations using simultaneous equations, but it only gave one critical point for $x,y \in [0,1]$. There are supposed to be 3 critical points. Is there a simpler/better method to get critical points? (working is as below)
***Also, is there a systemic method to check what type of extrema this critical point is?

*Simultaneous equations working:*
Solving for x and y in terms of $\lambda$ and substitute it into the 3rd equation:
$x^4+y^4-1=0  \implies (\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\lambda}})^4 + (\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}})^4-1 = 0 \implies \frac{1}{4\lambda^2}+\frac{1}{\lambda^2} = 1 \implies \lambda=\pm\frac{\sqrt5}{2}$
Hence, $x=\pm\sqrt\frac{1}{\sqrt5}$ and $\pm\sqrt-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}$, $y=\pm\sqrt\frac{2}{\sqrt5}$ and $\pm\sqrt-\frac{2}{\sqrt5}$.

Keeping in mind that $x,y \in [0,1]$, we ultimately have only one critical point:
$x = \sqrt\frac{1}{\sqrt5}$ and $y=\sqrt\frac{2}{\sqrt5}$

Comment: The level-curves of the function $ \ x^2 + 2y^2 \ $ are ellipses of varying "sizes" centered on the origin.  The three critical points in the first quadrant occur for the values of $ \ c \ $ in $ \ x^2 + 2y^2 \ = \ c \ \ $ where the major axis of the ellipse contacts the super-ellipse $ \ x^4 + y^4 \ = \ 1 \  \ ( y = 0 ) \ \   $ [the absolute minimum], where the minor axis does so $ \ ( x = 0 ) \ $ and where the ellipse just circumscribes the super-ellipse (corresponding  to the $ \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{\sqrt5}{2} \ $ case) [the absolute maximum].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

- From your equation $(1)$, you only get $\ x^2=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\ $ *if* $\ x\ne0\ $.  But $\ x=0\ $ is another solution of $(1)$, and this gives you another critical point.
- Likewise, $\ y=0\ $ is a solution of your equation $(2)$, and this gives you a third critical point.